# Is it possible make artificial gravitational waves?

Tags: gravity, space-time, gravitational-waves

Is it possible to generate gravitational waves (creating low or high disturbance in space-time) from very heavy bodies spinning at very high speed artificially?

Comment: By what definition would this make it "artificial" ?  And gravity is independent of a body's rotation rate unless you're proposing some sort of "dumbell" arrangement?

Comment: Making gravitational waves is easy. Making *detectable* gravitational waves is another matter.

Comment: If your question would be closed, I think it might be a better match on https://physics.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 4):

Typical accelerating masses will generate gravitational waves.  but because gravity is so weak of a force; and current/plausible near future detection apparatus will be unable to detect signals from anything less dense than gravitationally stable masses of degenerate matter (ie neutron stars or white dwarfs) moving at near relativistic speeds.

Comment: "Any moving mass will generate gravitational waves..." I think you might mean *accelerating mass*, not just moving. See [my mistake of understanding](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/507854/225215).

Comment: Not even "any accelerating mass".

Comment: @BMFForMonica Sorry for the off, what abbreviates "BMF"?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I should probably throw a delimiter between that and the "For Monica" part, huh? The BMF moniker is just my initials.

Comment: @BMFForMonica Ok, thanks! :-)